# Расширение Firefox для измерения ширины экрана похожее как в chrome

Tags: вёрстка, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-extension

При изменении ширины окна браузера, когда открыт Developer tools, в правом верхнем углу указывается ширина и высота окна. Очень удобно при верстке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли что-то подобное в Firefox или есть ли подобные расширения для него же?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+Shift+S (Debugger)
2. Toolbox Option
3. Ставим флажок возле Responsive Design Mode
4. Появится кнопка Responsive Design Mode
5. Нажимаем её и получаем возможность смотреть разрешение страницы, НО внутри окна браузера, впрочем ширину и высоту страницы изменять можно.